# Android multi screen rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es

Is it possible on Android to render specifically / only, to the connected Monitor/TV on the hdmi port?

If so, is it possible to use OpenGL ES to render a different scene on the monitor and on the device's screen?

I would like the tablet to become more of an input device when it is connected with a monitor/tv and my game to be rendered just to this screen. If nothing is connected, then the device's screen should be used.

Ideally I would render a small interface (with buttons and text only) on the android tablet and the game itself on the monitor.
Can this be done? How?

Comment: Sounds like a neat idea. Would be difficult to overcome the "flatness" of the "control pad", since the user would be looking at the larger screen not the tablet.

Comment: Great idea, a bit like the Wii U but with a better touch screen.